# How to un-compile an AutoHotkey file

Tags: compilation, autohotkey

I posted this earlier and made the error of assumming this was still the forum specific to AutoHotkey, and I apologize for that.

I have a compiled AutoHotkey file that I need to update, and I unfortunatly lost the original .ahk file in a hard drive crash.  I assume it is possible to un-compile it using the program, but do not know how, as this has not come up.  Any help I can get will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Open your autohotkey.exe file with an text editor. The code is in there.